# Nested for loop to match array of subtitles[0] with array of subdescriptions[0]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xml, for-loop

I'm using XML to create a framework for a website so that the content within the site can be easily modified by another party without heavy HTML work. Right now I'm trying to align my h3 headers with their respective paragraph elements but it ends up assigning each  all of the  elements when it should be that the first  gets the first  element and the second  gets the second  element.

My XML is something like this

```
<steps>
<step number="1">
    <title>Domain Name</title>
    <description>Before getting the server setup, we have to make sure that we have a name visible to the public. It would be pretty outrageous to ask users to remember our site based on the IP address (E.g. 52.25.195.213). IP addresses are hard to remember and mean virtually nothing to humans - which is why we need a nice plain text name to be remembered by.
    </description>
    <subtitle>Getting Logged Into Amazon Web Services</subtitle>
    <subdescription>As I mentioned in the overview to this guide, we will be using Amazon Web Services for the first 5 steps and because of that, you will need to create an account on their site. Again if you have a RHEL server already, please proceed to step 5 or 6 depending on whether or not you know how to connect to your server. If you are new to Amazon Web Services, hosting a micro server will cost you virtually nothing, but you will still need to provide your credit card information to prove that AWS can bill you should you incur charges (For the purpose of this guide, we will only be setting up one micro server, and as such you will be billed the minimal amount even if your server runs 24/7). After your first year of operation you will not be covered under the free tier, so please refer to this page to get the most up-to-date pricing information. Now that we've covered the not so exciting topic of cost, let's log in to AWS and get started!
    </subdescription>
    <subtitle>Picking Your Server Farm</subtitle>
    <subdescription>Upon logging in you should see your dashboard which contains lots of icons. If your layout is somehow different because you are a new user, don't panic. This just means that you will have to do a bit of searching to find the services I mention. To start, let's designate a desired server farm. This decision is not particularly important to average web users, as they will access your site from all over the world. However, for you the admin, the server farm should be as close to you as possible to avoid unnecessary latency. To select a server farm, go to the drop-down next to your name, and pick a location (for me North Virginia is the best pick because I live closer to the east coast).
    </subdescription>
</step>
<steps>
```

And the for-loops, which are in the HTML file in the  tag are like this

```
html += "<h2>" + title + "</h2>";
html += "<hr/>";
html += "<p>" + description + "</p>";
    for (var j = 0; j < subtitles.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < subdescriptions.length; k++) {
            html += "<h3>" + subtitles[j].innerHTML + "</h3>";
                html += "<p>" + subdescriptions[k].innerHTML + "</p>";
             }
    }
```

This is the resulting image; it's using subtitle[0] and displaying it with all the subdescriptions in the array.
[image]

EDIT:

@MikeMcCaughan I didn't initially include this part in my question but subtitles and subdescriptions are assigned through these lines

```
var allSteps = xml.querySelectorAll('step');
for(var i = 0; i < allSteps.length; i++){
    var step = allSteps[i];
    var subtitles = step.querySelectorAll('subtitle');
var subdescriptions = step.querySelectorAll('subdescription');
```

Comment: Surround your h3 and p with a div so each group will be separately

Comment: I would recommend considering the switch to an HTML templating library (for example handlebars.js). Building HTML the way you do it is far from optimal and fixing this approach might be a less ideal use of your time than learning how to use a utility that has been specifically made for this kind of work.

Comment: It would appear as though you're missing some important code; namely, how `subtitles` is getting assigned.

Comment: @Tomalak Wow thank you. That's... such an amazingly convenient way to go about this. I will definitely look into that once I figure this out; I don't want to scrap this just yet.

Comment: What you would need is a library that converts XML to a nested object for you (there are plenty of those, pick one that seems popular and try it out). Once that's done, you can feed that object to Handlebars (which cannot deal with XML directly but works just fine on nested objects) and write a template that matches your data structure. No manual loop writing, no accidentally invalid HTML, clean separation of code and data.